# How to increase Google Colab storage capacity

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working on a Dataset of 70gb with GPU.

Can someone suggest any possible way to make a new Notebook with more than 300Gbs Available or any possible way to go back to previous state.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by the following approach to make a new Notebook with more than 300GB:

1. Buy extra space in the corresponding account, either it will be in gdrive or in GCP storage then mount in Notebook.
2. Also, there is an option to mount multiple drive sources, sharing the following example to mount multiple gdrive for your reference. It will be useful if you have multiple gdrive accounts having more space altogether and feasible to use big space from different mount points.

> #Code base to mount first mount point:
>
> ```
> from google.colab import drive
> drive.mount('/content/drive01')
> ```
>
> #Follow the verification process, and enter the token
>
> #Code base to mount second mount point:
>
> ```
> !apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common module-init-tools
> !add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
> !apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
> !apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
>
> from google.colab import auth
> from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
> import getpass
>
> auth.authenticate_user()
> creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
> prompt = !google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
> vcode = getpass.getpass(prompt[0] + '\n\nEnter verification code: ')
> !echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
> !sudo mkdir /content/drive02
> !google-drive-ocamlfuse /content/drive02
> ```
>
> Follow the verification process, and enter the token twice. Please,
> note that you need to click on the account authentication URL twice
> and enter the token separately.
>
> Credit (Some issue has been fixed) -
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQ3CUHjbJ0w